# Is there a way to stop SVN logs telling me that a whole paragraph has been edited when only a single character change?

Tags: svn

Suppose I have a document under SVN. My collaborator removed a comma from where I had typed one incorrectly. I get an email to show me that an edit has been made, and the log tells me that an entire paragraph (the one containing the comma) has been removed, and has been replaced by a new one. On closer inspection, I see that the paragraphs are almost identical, and so I find it time-consuming searching through the paragraphs) to determine what has been edited.

I've been told that, in order to avoid this issue, I should regularly press 'enter'/ 'return' in the editor that I write the document with. The 'problem' is that in my editor, when I get to the end of the screen, it just moves to the next line down (obviously). However, SVN doesn't understand that this is a new line (and the whole paragraph ends up being on one line). If, when I get to the end of a line in the editor, I just press enter, the SVN issue is solved. However, things quickly get messy in the editor, and it's a right pain in the arse to see what's going on.

Does anyone know of a solution to this (common?) problem?

**Note:**
Unfortunately, I can't say anything more about the workings behind these SVN emails I get. All I really know is that some 'system' has been developed to do this where I work.

Answer (score 1):

SVN is doing exactly what it's designed to do, and without compiling your own custom version you won't change it. Except the data required to do what you're looking for doesn't actually exist anyway.

Your editor is doing what's known as "soft wrapping" - it's line-wrapping for your convenience in looking at the file, but not actually inserting any newline characters. The "new lines" you are seeing **aren't actually new lines** as far as the actual file contents are concerned. If you change the width of your editor's workspace (perhaps by making the window wider), you'll see the line wrapping change. Or if you open the file in an editor that doesn't soft wrap, you'll find a lot of horizontal scrolling.

If you don't like how SVN is presenting the diffs, tell your editor to force a newline at a set number of characters, or start pressing Enter where you want a line break.

Comment: Yeah, you know exactly what I'm saying. I guess might be solvable at the editor end. Let's say I write a document (mainly paragraphs) in my editor such that there are about 10 words per line (i.e. I press enter every 10 words or so). The problems arise when this is edited (which *will* be the case, I mean, I am using SVN after all). As you can imagine, it gets incredibly messy and hard to read.

Comment: The perceived problem is *only* solvable in the editor, because your issue is with the data you're producing and checking into SVN. I suggest you just deal with it, and find better diff tools that will help you find the change within the line. WinMerge is good for this IME.

Comment: It's not really accurate to say that the data to display what he wants doesn't exist.  It's right there, it's just that the unified diff format doesn't make it easy to see.

Answer (score 1):

You're essentially complaining about the limitations of the unified diff output.  Unified diffs are line oriented and so they're not particularly good at visualizing deltas that have a long line with a single byte change.  Subversion uses unified output because often it's sufficient to understand the change, can be understood by computers and people and is compatible with a lot of different pieces of software.

However, you can tell Subversion to [use a different tool to generate the diff](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.externaldifftools.html) that can display exactly what you want.  For instance I often use the [Kaleidoscope](http://www.kaleidoscopeapp.com/) diff tool for this purpose.  There is a list (probably incomplete) here of such tools:
https://wiki.apache.org/subversion/ListOfDiffApplications

In general you're going to probably need a GUI diff tool in order to visualize such changes (though it's possible there are some command line tools that can do it as well, janos mentions colordiff but I have no experience with it).  Off hand I know in addition to Kaleidoscope that [p4merge](http://www.perforce.com/product/components/perforce-visual-merge-and-diff-tools) can do this as well (though it doesn't wrap long lines making it harder to see).

Answer (score 1):

> I find it time-consuming searching through the paragraphs) to determine what has been edited.

It's slightly another problem, than "softwrapping vs hardwrapping". If you can, you have to use any visualdiff (GUI) tools, which support inline editing mode and reply of diff *in this tool*, not from email's diffs

Sample of my proofreading in TortoiseMerge (part of changes in latest revision) for text with softwrapping

[image: Diff in TMerge]